# ¿Cómo obtener un intervalo de valores en un vector en R?

Tags: r, vectores

Tengo el siguiente vector

```
pH <- c(8.2,8.2,8.4,8.1,8.2,8,8.2,8.3,8.2,8.12,8.2,8.13,8.06,
        8.1,8.16,8.11,8.26,8.19,8.16,8.28,8.17,8.14,8.19,8.12,
        8.22,8.1,8.07,8.13,8.09,8.2,8.46,8.32,8.89,8.33,8.85,
        8.4,8.84,8.55,8.87,8.49,8.4,8.86,8.33,8.85,8.36,8.19,
        8.85,9,8.55,8.26,8.7,8.86,8.75,8.74,8.81,8.59,8.84,8.02,
        8.33,8.53,8.36,8.66,8.15,8.11,8.25,8.12,8.17,8.38,8.18,
        8.34,8.16,8.25,8.1,8,8.24,8.05,8.05,7.83,8.09,8.03,8.09,
        8.21,8.09,8.21,8.09,7.98,8.11,8.36,8.13,7.97,7.92,8.07,
        8.04,8.19,8.13,8.11,8.1,8.13,8.18,8.15,8.24,7.85,8.32,
        8.05,6.91,8.05,6.61,8.02,7.55,8.11,8.1,8.18,8.04,8.39,
        8.13,8.14,8.3,8.32,8.38,8.1,8.1,8.12,8.05,8.21,8.19,
        8.18,8.34,7.71,8.13,8.09)
```

Y quiero obtener los valores que estén en el intervalo de 7.5 a 7.9

Comment: Puedes mostrar que has intentado hacer?

Answer (score 2):

La forma más simple es mediante una comparación de los valores:

```
pH[pH >= 7.5 & pH <= 7.9]

[1] 7.83 7.85 7.55 7.71
```

Básicamente se trata de una selección clásica de R por valores lógicos, la comparación `pH >= 7.5 & pH <= 7.9)` nos retorna un vector de lógicos del mismo tamaño de `pH`:

```
pH >= 7.5 & pH <= 7.9

  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [28] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [55] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [64] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [73] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [82] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [91] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[100] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[109]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[118] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[127] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

los valores `TRUE`, son los que terminan filtrandose. Algo parecido pero usando la función `subset()`:

```
subset(pH, pH >= 7.5 & pH <= 7.9)
```